# Basic authentication via nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx ingress controller (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) on AWS. The backend service (kibana from ECK: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-operator-config.html) uses HTTP basic auth mechanics.

Is there a way to tune nginx so that it appends Authorization: Basic header to every request forwarded to my service so that users won't have to type the password?

This solution did not work for me:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Authorization: Basic encoded_credentals";
```

as I am still being prompted for a password.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an ingress rule using a secret that contains a file generated with htpasswd. It's important the file generated is named auth (actually - that the secret has a key data.auth), otherwise the ingress-controller returns a 503.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-auth
  annotations:
    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Secret creation

```
$ htpasswd -c auth foo
New password: <bar>
New password:
Re-type new password:
Adding password for user foo
$ kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
secret "basic-auth" created
$ kubectl get secret basic-auth -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  auth: Zm9vOiRhcHIxJE9GRzNYeWJwJGNrTDBGSERBa29YWUlsSDkuY3lzVDAK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: basic-auth
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
```

Access it using curl and you should get 200 Ok.

```
$ curl -v http://10.2.29.4/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' -u 'foo:bar'
```

Check this example [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/basic)

Comment: This adds an authentication layer which is exactly the opposite to what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay maybe I have  misunderstood it...if the user is not entering the password from where you want the password to be coming?

Answer (score 7):

Solution:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    more_set_input_headers "Authorization: Basic <based64 user:pass>";
```